# How to get Buy anywhere API credential fo Plimus Sandbox?

Tags: php, api, joomla, integration, bluesnap

I am integrating my extension with Plimus by batch process.
It requires Buy Anywhere API credential, but I am not able to find it anywhere.

As per their API documentation

> Every API request must include authentication using the seller’s Buy
>   Anyware API credentials (username and password), which are different
>   to the seller’s Control Panel credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found :

> The API is currently not open for all vendors. In order to be approved
>   for the API you should send a request to vendors@plimus.com and the
>   request will be forwarded to our API team for review.
>
> As the API requires a certain, standard, your account will be reviewed
>   to check for your compatibility to an API system and a reply will be
>   sent back to you with the results.